# 膨大なサードパーティjarをMavenで管理できるでしょうか

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonatype-nexus, jar

とてもレガシーな案件に参画したのですが、最適化したいと考えています。

- 開発言語：Java
- 開発環境：Eclipse

現状は、大昔に当該案件の誰かが作った約1000個のjarファイルがフォルダに平置きされています。
新規にプロジェクトを作る際には、そのフォルダをビルドパスに通して開発を進めます。
以下の作業を改善したいのです。

1. Eclipseにてプロジェクト新規作成
2. ファイルサーバから1000個のjarをローカルPCにコピー
3. 上記2のjarが格納されているフォルダを1で作成したプロジェクトにビルドパス設定

できるかどうかはおいておいて、以下のような方法ができればなと思いました。

- 1000個のjarを1つのjarにまとめなおす
- 1000個のjarを自前のMavenリポジトリに登録してpomで管理する
- etc

その他、何かあればご教示いただきたいしだいです。
1000個という膨大な数なので環境整備するより今まで通りビルドパス通す方がよっぽど楽ならばその様にご指摘頂ければと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1000個のjarを1つのjarにまとめなおす

MANIFESTに特に設定がなければ、全jarファイルを同一ディレクトリに展開して、
再度、`jar`コマンドでアーカイブし直せば、1つのjarファイルにできるかと思います。
(MANIFESTのマージが必要な場合は、jarごとに確認する必要があると思います)

デプロイを考えると、1つにまとめてよいなら、まとめた方がよいかと思います。